# check code for android lower api compatibility

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

My project minSdkVersion is set to 10.
MainActivity is a ActionBarActivity from **support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity**.
the default method `.invalidateOptionsMenu()` crashes on Android 2.3.7 (api10) so I must use the compatibility method `.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`; 
and I have a question:

*Why does Android Studio not alert me that `invalidateOptionsMenu` is not for the older api?*

I understood this only after I succesfully build an apk and ran it on an api10 device and it crashed...

*How can I check without any real testing?*

Same thing with the PopupMenu
if I mistakenly import `android.widget.PopupMenu` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu` I do not get a warning from AndroidStudio that minSdk set to 10 and PopupMenu will not work on old Android

Comment: Usually, Android Studio does warn you if you support lower API but your method is available only on higher APIs. Can't say why it didn't warn you...

Comment: You Android lint to check.

Comment: @JaredBurrows the red error shown only when I open class file with new api code. now i do next: open all my classes and see where is red error. but in future I want that Studio show me all classes with unsupported api. I don't understand why app build succesfully.  in Eclipse immediately shows in which file error and build not work. but studio...

Comment: `but in future I want that Studio show me all classes with unsupported api. I don't understand why app build succesfully. ` Running different API compatible code on a real device is different than compiling the code. Do not rely on the IDE to make the correct decisions all the time. Use `gradlew lint` and read the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The Google documentation for [supporting different platform versions](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) provides some good insight. They even address the issue you were dealing with:

```
private void setUpActionBar() {
    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

My best suggestion beyond that would be to set your target API to the platform you want to test, see if it gives you any compiler level flags, and if not give it a quick run in the emulator. Hope that helps!